# How can I get more digits of polynomial trend-line in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, coefficients, trendline

The trendline equation in google sheets shows only 3 digits of each coefficient. When I want to draw the function with this equation, the accuracy is different. How can I get more digits of trendline function to get a more precise function?

Blue curve - google sheets trendline
Red curve - the function rebuilt from trendline coefficients.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about digits or coefficients? The 3rd coefficient has 4 digits precision.

Comment: I need to have more accurate trend-line function. I suppose the coefficients should have more digits. I had the same problem in Excel and adding more digits solved the problem.

I'd be glad to find any solution to correct the mistake in case it doesn't depend on coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the following formulas. It appears the functions in excel work for this also. For x,y include the ranges stated for x and y in your graph.

**3rd Order Polynomial Trendline**

Equation: y = (c3 * x^3) + (c2 * x^2) + (c1 * x^1) + b

c3: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2,3}),1)

c2: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2,3}),1,2)

C1: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2,3}),1,3)

b: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2,3}),1,4)

Reference:
http://www.exceltoolset.com/getting-coefficients-of-chart-trendline/

Answer (score 0):

On Google Sheets you will be able to change the coefficients number to improve the precision of a polynomial trend line.

Unfortunately, there is no way to act directly on the digits for each coefficient.

### Reference:

[Trendlines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines)

Comment: How can I change the coefficients (display more precise format in the graph)?

Answer (score 0):

I took my Sheets data over to Excel, created the trendline with the extra decimal places needed in the coefficients, then brought the trendline formula back over to Google Sheets. Hate that work around, but it only took a couple of minutes and the outcome was within needed accuracies.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. The excel works perfect but the point is, that the data in the sheet changes every day and the evaluation must be performed in google sheets to avoid additional work.

Comment: @Thomas Bickford how were you able to update the coefficients in Excel with extra decimal places? I can't seem to find the setting.